# How to convert string to another way and detect Linebreaks and write to text file in vb .net

Tags: vb.net

I have a srt file and I want to write it into a text file in another way with vb .net. So I have this string

```
1
00:00:01,600 --> 00:00:04,200
English (US)

2
00:00:05,900 --> 00:00:07,999
This is a subtitle in American English
Sometimes subtitles have 2 lines

3
00:00:10,000 --> 00:00:14,000
Adding subtitles is very easy to do
```

and want to write this format to text file into below format

```
1 # 00:00:01,600 # 00:00:04,200 # English (US)
2 # 00:00:05,900 # 00:00:07,999 # This is a subtitle in American English <br /> Sometimes subtitles have 2 lines
3 # 00:00:10,000 # 00:00:14,000 # Adding subtitles is very easy to do
```

How can I achieve that?
Especially line 2 that detects line break and insert a linebreak symbol to string.

Comment: The question is why do you need to "convert" some portion of text into different form? On the other hand - a suggestion: you have to post text rather than images.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok Dear Maciej Los thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to create custom class:

```
Public Class Subtitle
    Public Sub New(_id As Integer)
        ID = _id
    End Sub
    
    Public Property ID As Integer = 0
    Public Property Lines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        If Lines.Count <=2 Then
            Return $"{ID.ToString()} # {String.Join(" # ", Lines)}" 
        Else
            Return $"{ID.ToString()} # {String.Join(" # ", Lines.Take(2))} <br/> {String.Join("<br/>", Lines.Skip(2).Take(Lines.Count))}" 
        End If

    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
'define file name
Dim sFileName As String = "D:\test.srt"
'read all lines into variable (type of string array)
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(sFileName)

Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim sPattern As String = "^\d{1,}$" 
Dim oSubtitle As Subtitle = Nothing
Dim lstSubtitles As List(Of Subtitle) = New List(Of Subtitle)

Dim r As Regex = New Regex(sPattern)

Do While i < lines.Count
    If r.IsMatch(lines(i)) Then
        oSubtitle = New Subtitle(Convert.ToInt32(lines(i)))
        lstSubtitles.Add(oSubtitle)
    Else
        If lines(i)<> String.Empty Then oSubtitle.Lines.Add(lines(i).Replace("-->", "#"))
    End If
    i+=1
Loop

For Each oSubtitle In lstSubtitles
    Console.WriteLine(oSubtitle.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: Wow This is exactly what I was looking for, but what should I do if I want to import the .srt file via an open file dialog ?
Thank you for your prompt reply

Comment: You need to write code which will do that ;) I'm not going to write it for you.

Comment: can you help me please because I am not a professional And I do this for the convenience of my job and it has no commercial aspect

Comment: I've changed the code to read lines from `*.srt` file. If you want to use [OpenFIleDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=net-5.0), then read the documentation and change the code to your needs. Please, do not expect that i'll do everything what you ask. If my answer was helpful, please accept it.

Comment: Thank you a million times, I will not forget your help and you are the best and this code works well, God bless you  Your answer was unique, thank you

Comment: @vahidAraghi The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer. Click the check mark (tick mark) to the left of their answer. This will help future readers and earn you a few points.